"Distinguished" rise (ascent) in permutation. What exactly does it mean?
The text 'Analytic Combinatorics' by Flajolet & Sedgewick says that
(p.209 quote)
[Rises and ascending runs in permutations]
A rise(ascent) in a permutation $\sigma = \sigma_1\sigma_2....\sigma_n$  is a pair of consecutive elements $\sigma_i\sigma_{i+1}$ satisfying $\sigma_i<\sigma_{i+1}$
.... we tackle the easier problem of enumerating permutations with "distinguished" rises, of which the set is denoted by $\mathscr B$. For instance, $\mathscr B$ contains elements such as
2 6  1  3 $\nearrow$ 4 $\nearrow$ 8 $\nearrow$ 9 $\nearrow$ 11  15  12  5 $\nearrow$ 10  13  7  14
where those rises that are "distinguished" are represented by arrows. Note that some rises may NOT be "distinguished". ....
(quote)
Question :
"Distinguished" rise (ascent) in permutation. What exactly does it mean?
WHY NOT 2 $\nearrow$ 6 or 1 $\nearrow$ 3 or 10 $\nearrow$ 13 or 7 $\nearrow$ 14?

"Distinguished" just means "what we are interested in".
Consider this Illustrative Example :
We have a Museum with 8 "rooms" where we want to store 20 "Diamonds" for viewing.
We can try that with $n_1$ ways.
I may add a Condition that no room should be empty.
We can then try that with $n_2$ ways which is much less than $n_1$.
Here are the 8 rooms : $\text{ r r r r r r r r }$
Nothing is "Distinguished" here.
I will then add the Condition that the two central rooms must have $4,5,6$ (not less , not more) Diamonds.
Here are the 8 rooms : $\text { r r r } \overleftrightarrow { r } \overleftrightarrow { r } \text { r r r }$
Here those 2 rooms are "Distinguished"
The other 6 rooms might have $4,5,6$ (or less , or more) Diamonds , though we do not care.
We can then try that with $n_3$ ways which is much less than $n_2$.
Back to your Case :
We have 15 numbers :
$N N N N N N N N N N N N N N N$
Nothing is "Distinguished" here.
We want to count the ascents , which might work out to $m_1$ ascents via $n_4$ ways
I might add the Condition that I am interested in only the high-lighted Positions , which are then "Distinguished" :
$N N N \overleftrightarrow {N N N N N} N N \overleftrightarrow {N N} N N N$
When we count the ascents , which might work out to $m_2$ ascents via $n_5$ ways , where $m_2$ might be less than $m_1$ while $n_5$ might be more than $n_4$
Here , ascents might or might not occur outside the "Distinguished" Positions.
When I add the Condition that only the high-lighted "Distinguished" Positions should have ascents [ no ascents outside that range ] , then it might work out to $m_3$ ascents via $n_6$ ways
The Authors are giving techniques to calculate such numbers using Inclusion Exclusion Principle & generating functions & Etc.

What an easy explanation. Thank you.

If you extract the coefficients in Flajolet's BGF $B(z,v)$ and look them up on OEIS, they turn out to be tabulated as entry A090582. This includes the following entry which explicitly references Flajolet and Sedgwick, which I've converted into Mathjax:

Let $\mathcal{P}_n$ be the set of all $n$-permutations. Build a superset $\mathcal{Q}_n$ of $\mathcal{P}_n$ composed of $n$-permutations in which some (possibly all or none) ascents have been designated. An ascent in a permutation $\sigma_1 \sigma _2\cdots \sigma_n $ is a pair of consecutive elements $\sigma_i \sigma_{i+1}$. As a triangular array read by rows $T(n,k)$ [i.e., sequence A090582] is the number of elements in $\mathcal{Q}_n$ that have exactly $k$ distinguished ascents, $n \geq 1$, $0 \leq k \leq n-1$. Row sums are A000670. E.g.f. is $y/(1+y-\exp(yx))$. For example, $T(3,1)=6$ because there are four 3-permutations with one ascent, with these we would also count $1\nearrow 2 3$, and $12\nearrow 3$ where exactly one ascent is designated by "$\nearrow$". (After Flajolet and Sedgewick.)  -Geoffrey Critzer, Nov 13 2012

The reference to A000670 is also of note. It has e.g.f. $1/(2-\exp(x))$, which corresponds to Flajolet's $B(z)=B(z,1)$, and includes the following entry:

$a(n)$ is the number of ways to form a permutation of $[n]$ and then choose a subset of its descent set. - Geoffrey Critzer, Apr 29 2023

So presumably both entries are an attempt to explicate the treatment in Flajolet and Sedgwick.
Returning to the first cited entry, I'll consider the example of $n=3$ in more detail. There are six such $3$-permutations: $123,132,213,231,312,321.$ If we don't want any distinguished ascents, then each of these is a valid element and thus there are six permutations with zero distinguished ascents. However, note that $123$ contains two ascents while $321$ contains none.  As such, we can choose permutations with one distinguished ascent in the following six ways:
$$1\nearrow 23,~12\nearrow 3,~1\nearrow 32,~21\nearrow 3,~2\nearrow 31,31\nearrow 2$$
Note the two ways to include a distinguished ascent in $123$ whereas there are none for $321$. If we want to have two such distinguished ascents, then $1\nearrow 2\nearrow 3$ is the only option. If we lump these all together we end up with 13 examples, corresponding to $a(3)=13$.

To put a finer point on "WHY NOT 2 →6 or 1 → 3 or 10 → 13 or 7 → 14?" in Flajolet's example: You certainly could include some (or all) of these, and you could also choose to exclude some (or all) of the distinguished rises in Flajolet's example. These choices would simply give rise to other elements of $\mathcal{B}$.

Thank you for your answer. it's really helpful.
